# message sending issue via twilio

Tags: php, openssl, twilio, php-ini

I am using `twilio` to send message but having issue of `open ssl` extension it said that,

> uncaught exception,open ssl extension is not enabled

Then I uncommented open ssl in `php.ini` file but still facing same issue kindly guide me, please.

Comment: Add some  code that causing problem

Comment: Make sure you restart your server after uncommenting this.